# Template driven validation in angular 7

Tags: javascript, validation, angular6, angular5, angular7

I try to validate custom text box by template driven in angular 7 but not working.also i am not able to find this related question in google also..So any genius can resolve this issue?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhgkje?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
 <my-textbox type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" 
 [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required></my-textbox>
 <div *ngIf="f.submitted && firstName.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
 <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-validation.html
Not sure this helps, but here you can find some TextBox Validation

Comment: @MaulikSakhida:  I am asking in angular 7

Comment: What is the issue? I see that stackblitz code working fine - unless I am missing something, can you explain why you think its not working?

Comment: Can you wait few min?

Comment: @WandMaker:Can you answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316578/form-custom-fields-validation-angular-2